# Can tokens be converted to different symbols?

Tags: cv

Can tokens be changed to different symbols using the arrow power, or can only rolled dice be altered?

Comment: I presume the CV tag means we're talking about [this game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/143986/cv). If so, the question is probably clear to people who know the game.

Comment: Yes, that is the game. Did you want me to provide more clarification in the question? I'm used to questions only being clear when I know the general rules of the game being discussed, so wrote it that way.

Comment: I was actually commenting as a response to this question coming up as being flagged for being unclear in the review queue. I left my comment to clarify the "cv" tag (which didn't have a wiki entry at the time) to show that this question _isn't_ unclear, we just don't know the game! Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: That's one of the things I'm struggling with as a newcomer here... I sometimes have a hard time figuring out what game the question is related to when its title only appears in the tag. This also impacts search results: it's not the case here as CV is the title and the tag but take for instance Arcadia Quest which is the first time I ran into the "issue". Launch a search for "Arcadia Quest" and you get 2 results. By using the [arcadia-quest] tag you'll see that there are in fact 3 questions for this game. I think adding the game title in the subject (or in the body if the title is long) helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbols are used to purchase cards wherever they come from (Dice or Cards on your CV).
As you can only use each symbol once per turn, the symbols from your cards are materialized using tokens which are just a convenient way to remember that you already planned to use the symbol from one of your cards and to avoid that you use it twice...

The Arrows are explained on page 7 of the rulesbook and nothing mentions the source of the symbol there:

[image]

A symbol is a symbol is a symbol ;-)
And you can swap them wherever they come from...